# can't find package crontab-ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, bash, cron, schedule

I am trying to install `cron` for scheduling and before anyone says duplicate, I have tried the methods of `sudo apt-get update` and `upgrade` mentioned and they don't work.

When I go to install `crontab`, it tells me that it `cannot find the package`. if I do `apt-get install cron*`, it tells me that I have `broken packages`, though it won't say which ones. I have `cron`, that is, simple `cron` installed. Will that let me do all of the scheduling and manipulation of files that I need, or do I also need `crontab`? If I do, how can I get it when the above commands have failed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `crontab` file is indeed [provided](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=contents&keywords=crontab&mode=exactfilename&suite=precise&arch=any) by the `cron` package. This package is installed by default (See the 12.04 [Manifest](http://releases.ubuntu.com/12.04/ubuntu-12.04.4-desktop-amd64.manifest)).

The `crontab` command should already be in your `$PATH`:

```
$ type crontab
crontab is /usr/bin/crontab
```

Check the [Official documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CronHowto) to know how to set up your crontab.

Comment: `crontab is hashed /usr/bin/crontab` is the message it returns, what does this mean?

Comment: it means that you already have it ready to use. Did I answer your question?

Comment: well, will it do all of the same things as crontab? Will it let me schedule bashscripts and commands to run when I want them?

Comment: This is indeed the right tool to use to schedule scripts to run periodically

Comment: OK would you know the syntax to run a script called sysstattest.sh every 3 minutes? If my script has multiple choices(1 for vmstat, 2 for iostat and 3 for sar) can it still run them all with cron and write the output to file?

Comment: can cron arrange give them any priority?

Comment: @paul Could you please create a new question to cover the crontab creation?

Comment: created new question at http://askubuntu.com/questions/593309/how-to-output-sysstat-to-cron-or-other-scheduling-script